# Error:Unity to xcode; Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

Tags: xcode, augmented-reality

Right now, I am making an augmented reality with unity.
And I tried building with x-code.
But I got the following error.
If you have a similar experience, please advise me.
Mu Unity's build setting is ARM46

```
●Error：
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARObjectScanningConfiguration", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARKitNativeObjectDetection.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARObjectAnchor", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARKitNativeObjectDetection.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARPointCloud", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARPointCloud.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AREnvironmentProbeAnchor", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
   objc-class-ref in AREnvironmentProbe.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARReferenceImage", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AROrientationTrackingConfiguration", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARImageAnchor", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARAnchor", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARWorldMap", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARWorldMap.o
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
   objc-class-ref in ARKitNativeObjectDetection.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARPlaneAnchor", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARSession", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ARReferenceObject", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in ARWorldMap.o
   objc-class-ref in ARSessionNative.o
   objc-class-ref in AREnvironmentProbe.o
   objc-class-ref in ARKitNativeObjectDetection.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's missing library.

In your Unity3D project, please make sure XR is enabled.

If you are using the latest version of Unity3D, you have to enable ARKit Build Settings in Project Settings. Meanwhile, in XR Plug-in Management(iOS), you have to toggle on the ARKit as Plug-in Providers.

and of course, don't forget to add camera usage description in build settings.

Comment: Thank you for replying!

After I add Window>PackageManager>ARFoundation & AR kit Pluguin, I can build!

but I had new Error;
Ethan has denied the launch request. Internal launch error: process launch failed: failed to get the task for process -1

Now, I am searching

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!
I solved!

1st Step

I add XR Foundation & XR kit Pluguin
(window > Package Manager)

2nd Step

I changed setting of xcode(singin)
all setting change iOS developer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xoCu.png)